# Promblems with the code when using Math.toDegrees

Tags: java

Can someone tell me why my code is not working with Degrees,All is fine with Radians,but in this task I'm need to have 40 degrees.Why when I'm using Degrees I only have 1 loop step?

[Working code with Radians](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nDSl.png).
[Not working code with Degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc2Fq.png)

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
double g=8.86,a=40; // a=lenkis
double v0,x,y,t;
boolean bulletInFlight = true;
boolean hitTarget = false;

System.out.println("191RDB107 Vladislavs Fedotovs");
System.out.println("While operators,07,Urans");

System.out.print("v0=");
if (sc.hasNextDouble())
v0 = sc.nextDouble();
else {
    System.out.println("input-output error");
    sc.close();
    return;

}
sc.close();
System.out.println("result:");
System.out.println("t \t x \t y");
t = 0.1;
while(bulletInFlight) {

    x =v0*t*Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(40));                   ||Main Problem
    y =v0*t*Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(40))-(g*Math.pow(t, 2))/2; ||Main Problem
    System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);
    if (x >= 12  && x <= 17 && y <=-2 && y >=-4) // red target 
    {
        bulletInFlight = false;
        hitTarget = true;
        t+=0.05;
    }else if ((x>= 0 && x<=10 && y<0)|| (x>10 && x<12 && y<=-4) ||(x>10 && y<=-4)) // green grass
    {
        bulletInFlight = false;
        t+=0.05;    
    }else
                t+=0.05;
    }if (hitTarget)
     System.out.println("the target was destroyed");

     else
         System.out.println("shot off the target");
    }
}
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nDSl.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc2Fq.png
```

Comment: `Math.toDegrees()` takes a parameter that's in radians, and converts it to degrees.  I'm pretty sure that you *don't* want the degrees representation of 40 radians here.  `Math.toRadians()` does the reverse: It takes a value in degrees, and returns the equivalent in radians.

Comment: Perhaps you meant 'toRadians(40)'.  Java's trig functions all take radians

Comment: you definitively need `toRadians()` since `sin()` and `cos()` expected the argument in radians

Comment: Oh ok,Thanks,My bad!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't followed your code but the following looks suspicous.

```java
    x =v0*t*Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(40));                   ||Main Problem
    y =v0*t*Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(40))-(g*Math.pow(t, 2))/2; ||Main Problem
```

Math.toDegrees converts radians to degrees.  But 40 looks awful big to be radians.

Perhaps you meant `Math.toRadians()`.